# Cant install Klarna on magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, composer, php-7.2

I tried to install `Klarna` in my `Magento 2.3.2` website using 
composer trollweb.
I kept getting errors as the `klarna checkout was not working`.

In the end, I used `mage2pro klarna` to set it up

Is there any way I can install `klarna` on my `Magento 2.3.2` site ?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your idea, You should use command for install klarna payment for magento 2:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:disable
composer require klarna/m2-payments // support M 2.2.x
or
composer require klarna/m2-checkout // support M 2.3.x
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [languages] (eg: en_US de_AT de_DE fi_FI sv_SE)
php bin/magento cache:enable
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Go to admin page enable klarna payment

Comment: did that but get :

[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package klarna/m2-payments. Check the
  package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available
   in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable). 

Also note that i am using magento 2.3.2 and klarna payments only work for magento 2.2

Comment: You can install klanra checkout

```composer require klarna/m2-checkout```

Docs: https://marketplace.magento.com/klarna-m2-checkout.html

Comment: doesnt work out... it keeps giving me that error in my last chat